# Diff Tool which Outputs 1/0 // Yes/No

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'am searching for an Tool in !PHP! that will return maybe an Array or just something, with which i can lookup if there are any Changes.

Its beeing used to get Data from MySQL turning it into a JSON File and if the JSON File differs from the MySQL Output, then the file should be new generated.

So i just need to type a Function or something else, if there's been changes made, (Yes/No) do X.

Do you guys know any Tool that would work with my Idea?

Thanks for Helping me out.

Comment: you can use if condition ..I think you can do it with if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague but, if I understood right, here is an idea:

```
<?php 
class Tool {
  var $db; // you will have to provide a valid db connection

  function __construct (& $db) {
   $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function execute ($query, $file){
    $arr = $this->fetch($query);
    $dbJSON = json_encode($arr);

    $fileJSON = file_get_contents($file);

    if( md5($dbJSON) != md5($fileJSON) ){
      $this->write($dbJSON, $file);
    }
  }

  protected function fetch($sql) {
    $arr = array();
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
   if($result){
     // Cycle through results
     while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
       $arr[] = $row;
     }
     // Free result set
     $result->close();
   }
   return $arr;
  }

  protected function write ($content, $file) {
    $fp = fopen('w+', $file);
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
  } 
}
```

?>

and a use case:

```
<?php
  $db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');

  // Check for errors
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
  }else{
    $tool = new Tool($db);
    $tool->execute('SELECT * FROM users','/com/user.json');
  }
?>
```